# Calculate the difference between the multinomial probability

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution, discrete-data

I have an example data as follows:

```
df <- matrix(c(18, 54, 33, 75, 24, 15, 23, 15, 8), nrow=3, byrow=T)
dimnames(df) <- list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('low', 'moderate', 'high'))
names(dimnames(df))<-c("medicine", "level")
df
```

Output:

```
        level
medicine low moderate high
       a  18       54   33
       b  75       24   15
       c  23       15    8
```

How can I construct approximate 95% confidence intervals  for difference between the probability that a drup `a` is highly effective and the probability that `b` is highly  effective in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simply:
$$\frac{33}{33+54+18}-\frac{8}{8+15+23}.$$

Comment: Thank u, but I'm not sure if it's that simple. :). I have considered use method from here. https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_02.html

Comment: BTW, do u know how to calculate in your approach with R?

Comment: Well, confidence intervals are another matter... my answer is just the estimate of the difference in probabilities

Comment: Sorry, confidence intervals should be taken into account, please check update of my question.